# Buttons behavior between PC and Touch devices (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, click, touch, toggle

Basically I am a web designer and I don't know much about jQuery so I'm a little bit lost. I wrote some jQuery scripts to manage buttons but they don't have the behavior as I would like on PC and on Touch devices.

I have two families of buttons to manage. The "images" buttons (swap) and the CSS buttons (background color change).

I would like to disable the "hover" effect on Touch devices because it's mismanaged but keep the mouse clicks on Touch devices AND PC. But the drama is there.

Here is a model that I created: [Model](http://pepitodanger.free.fr/)

Here is the mess I wrote:

```
// Rollover on image
$(function() {
    $('img.rollover').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
        this.src = this.src.replace("-normal","-hover");
    });

    $('img.rollover').on('mouseleave', function(){
        this.src = this.src.replace("-hover","-normal");
    });
});

// Toggles forms
$(function() {
    $("#form-contact").hide();
    $("#form-devis").hide();

      $("#btn-contact").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("btn-form-hover");    
        $("#form-contact").fadeToggle(500, "linear");
        $("#form-devis").hide();
        $("#btn-devis").removeClass("btn-form-hover");
  });

    $("#btn-devis").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("btn-form-hover");
        $("#form-devis").fadeToggle(500, "linear");
        $("#form-contact").hide();
        $("#btn-contact").removeClass("btn-form-hover");
  });
});

// Toggle client area
$(function() {
    $("#div-client-area").hide();

        $("#btn-clients").click(function(){ 
        $("#div-home").toggle(500,"linear");
        $("#div-client-area").toggle(500,"linear");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By default touch devices don't support hover. However it seems that you're trying to create the hover effect with jQuery, which you don't necessarily need to! Just use CSS to do it, with `div:hover{ cursor:pointer; background-color: xyz... }`. This will apply on desktop but not on touch.

Alternatively you can use a lightweight library called [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect the existence of touch events in the browser. It will add classes to the `<html>` tag depending on features being available. One of the features it tests for is touch, so you could check if the class is there and form conditional statements accordingly. Something like `if($("html").hasClass("touch"){ ... })`.

Hope that gives you a broad direction.